# Can't get my if statement to work with html form input in js

Tags: javascript, html

Without my if statement I'm able to store the data but when i want to check against an html form value, Im unable to do so.
P.S I'm fairly new to js so please bear with me.

```
<script>
var signupForm = document.getElementById('signup-form');
var signupSuccess = document.getElementById('signup-success');
var signupError = document.getElementById('signup-error');
var signupBtn = document.getElementById('signup-button');
var day_Imp = document.getElementById('D-day').value;
var onSignupComplete = function(error) {
  signupBtn.disabled = false;
  if (error) {
    signupError.innerHTML = 'Sorry. Your Booking failed.';
  } else {
    signupSuccess.innerHTML = 'Thanks for playing at Total Football!';
    // hide the form
    signupForm.style.display = 'none';
  }
};

function signup(formObj) {
    console.log(day_Imp);
    // Store emails to firebase
    if(day_Imp==='monday'){
        var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://fiery-torch-164.firebaseio.com/days/monday");
        myFirebaseRef.push({
          email: formObj.email.value,
          name: formObj.name.value,
          number: formObj.number.value,
        }, onSignupComplete);
        signupBtn.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="infoCSS.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="signup">
    <h2 class="signup-title">Enter your information please</h2>
    <p id="signup-success" class="text-success"></p>
    <p id="signup-error" class="text-danger"></p>
    <form class="signup-form form-inline" id="signup-form" role="form" onsubmit="return signup(this)">
        <label>Full Name</label><br><br>
        <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" required><br><br>
        <label>Email</label><br><br>
        <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email. eg., joe@acme.com" required><br><br>
        <label>Cell Phone</label><br><br>
        <input class="form-control" name="number" type="tel" required><br><br>
        <label>Day</label><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="D-day"><br><br>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="signup-button" type="submit" >#Allin!</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    var signupForm = document.getElementById('signup-form');
    var signupSuccess = document.getElementById('signup-success');
    var signupError = document.getElementById('signup-error');
    var signupBtn = document.getElementById('signup-button');
  //  var day_Imp = document.getElementById('D-day');
    var onSignupComplete = function(error) {
      signupBtn.disabled = false;
      if (error) {
        signupError.innerHTML = 'Sorry. Your Booking failed.';
      } else {
        signupSuccess.innerHTML = 'Thanks for playing at Total Football!';
        // hide the form
        signupForm.style.display = 'none';
      }
    };
    
    function signup(formObj) {

  // Store emails to firebase
  $('#D-day').on('input', function() {
    var day_Imp = document.getElementById('D-day').value;
    console.log(day_Imp);

    if (day_Imp == 'monday') {
      var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://fiery-torch-164.firebaseio.com/days/monday");
      myFirebaseRef.push({
        email: formObj.email.value,
        name: formObj.name.value,
        number: formObj.number.value,
      }, onSignupComplete);
      signupBtn.disabled = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the updated version including all the html and js.

Comment: What kind of element is `day_Imp`?

Comment: is `if(day_Imp==='monday')` where you check? if yes, why do you use `===`? use `==` instead..

Comment: what does your log statement `console.log(day_Imp);` output?

Comment: day_Imp is the variable in which im trying to store the value from the html input field whose id is D-day

Comment: the user enters the data in input field, i need to check if he enters monday 
if yes then the code executes

Comment: mpadittech i thought to check if i was really getting the value in the js variable.....i tired to check in the firebox console.

Comment: lal13: Sir no go on the '=='
the data is still not passed

Comment: "what does your log statement console.log(day_Imp); output?"

And change it to console.log(day_Imp, typeof day_Imp, day_Imp.length);

Comment: i just commented it.
It was just to check if i was getting the input in the variable

Answer (score 0):

## Simple Demo

In **jQuery** you can do this with http://api.jquery.com/on/ `.on('input', function(){...})`

```js
$('#D-day').on('input', function() {
  var day_Imp = document.getElementById('D-day').value;

  if (day_Imp == 'monday') {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = day_Imp;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="D-day">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

The most important is that it populates to `<p>` this typed text.

## Example (updated)

So try this and let me know if it works

```js
var signupForm = document.getElementById('signup-form');
var signupSuccess = document.getElementById('signup-success');
var signupError = document.getElementById('signup-error');
var signupBtn = document.getElementById('signup-button');
var onSignupComplete = function(error) {
  signupBtn.disabled = false;
  if (error) {
    signupError.innerHTML = 'Sorry. Your Booking failed.';
  } else {
    signupSuccess.innerHTML = 'Thanks for playing at Total Football!';
    // hide the form
    signupForm.style.display = 'none';
  }
};

function signup(formObj) {

  // Store emails to firebase
  $('#D-day').on('input', function() {
    var day_Imp = document.getElementById('D-day').value;
    console.log(day_Imp);

    if (day_Imp == 'monday') {
      var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://fiery-torch-164.firebaseio.com/days/monday");
      myFirebaseRef.push({
        email: formObj.email.value,
        name: formObj.name.value,
        number: formObj.number.value,
      }, onSignupComplete);
      signupBtn.disabled = true;
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="D-day">
```

## workaround

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="infoCSS.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="signup">
    <h2 class="signup-title">Enter your information please</h2>
    <p id="signup-success" class="text-success"></p>
    <p id="signup-error" class="text-danger"></p>
    <form class="signup-form form-inline" id="signup-form" role="form" onsubmit="return signup()">
      <label>Full Name</label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" id="n" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Email</label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" id="e" placeholder="Your email. eg., joe@acme.com" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Cell Phone</label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input class="form-control" name="number" type="tel" id="cp" required>
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Day</label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="D-day">
      <br>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="signup-button" type="submit">#Allin!</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    var signupForm = document.getElementById('signup-form');
    var signupSuccess = document.getElementById('signup-success');
    var signupError = document.getElementById('signup-error');
    var signupBtn = document.getElementById('signup-button');
     //  var day_Imp = document.getElementById('D-day');
    var onSignupComplete = function(error) {
      signupBtn.disabled = false;
      if (error) {
        signupError.innerHTML = 'Sorry. Your Booking failed.';
      } else {
        signupSuccess.innerHTML = 'Thanks for playing at Total Football!';
        // hide the form
        signupForm.style.display = 'none';
      }
    };

    function signup() {

      // Store emails to firebase
      $('#D-day').on('input', function() {
        var day_Imp = document.getElementById('D-day').value;
        console.log(day_Imp);

        if (day_Imp == 'monday') {
          var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://fiery-torch-164.firebaseio.com/days/monday");
          myFirebaseRef.push({
            email: $('#e').val(),
            name: $('#n').val(),
            number: $('#cp').val(),
          }, onSignupComplete);
          signupBtn.disabled = true;
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but i need to check if the data from the user matches the string i provide 
like i need to match the user input with 'monday'

Comment: could it be in jQuery instead of pure JS?

Comment: Grisza I tried the code you provided, still no storage :/

Comment: Did you include jquery in HTML in <head>? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​ you must also invoke the function signup with proper argument. Include HTML file then we can see your form. I try do similar to this.

Comment: see this update of code and below var_Imp proper scope I change the scope of var day_Imp that's why didn't work because day_Imp was out of a $('#D-day').on('input', function() {...

Comment: grisza I've attached the whole code snippet. Kindly have a look at it please and point out the mistake.

Comment: so the user can add the info once, after that the form is not displayed anymore.

Comment: I added ID's to few inputs and workaround if formObj not works so get value of id each input. This workaround must work